# How to get an image from a site using rvest?

Tags: r, image, web-scraping

The site is https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=cat and I want to pick the first image. My code is

```
image_link = 'https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=cat'
read_html(image_link) %>%
  html_node(".photo-list-photo-container") %>%
  html_attr("src")
```

which gives me NA as a result? I also tried replacing `html_node` by `html_element` but it didn't work too.

How can one do this?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
read_html(image_link) %>% html_node(".photo-list-photo-container") %>%
  html_node("img") %>% html_attr("src")
```